# How to pass zuul proxy server request by eureka server in spring microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have tried the following link example
https://exampledriven.wordpress.com/2016/07/06/spring-cloud-zuul-example/

and I have found if I shut down the Eureka server or service then still the Zuul proxy service sending a response to the other microservices.

Anyone know how to pass the zuul service request via Eureka server.It means if Eureka server gets down then proxy server do not have to send the response to the other microservice.

Comment: Please share application.properties

Comment: In above mention link, there is 3 project which contains its individual application.yml file.Please kindly refer that.